# Android - Help me with ArrayList

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

I have a problem here. I want to test my parser result.

I have a KML document from request to Google Maps. here is my KML document:

```
<Placemark>
<name>Head north on Jalan Kebagusan Raya toward Jalan Anggrek</name>
<description><![CDATA[go 850&#160;m]]></description>
<address>Jalan Kebagusan Raya</address>
....
....
....
</Placemark>
```

I wanna to save a tag `<name>` to my variable.
Can you help me to solve my problems? It's easy to save a string, int, or even double from parsing result. But to save a sentences like "Head north on Jalan Kebagusan Raya toward Jalan Anggrek".

Comment: Why can't you save the sentence as a string??

Comment: if i save it to string, it makes difficult to split it with delimiter like (" ") or ("-")

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Example Link for the same

https://github.com/frogermcs/RoutePathExample